# Updating Input Field Value from Dropdown Selection with Javascript (in Dubsado CRM Form)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I use a platform called Dubsado as a CRM. They allow you to add custom HTML (including <script> tags) to their forms, but I cannot get this particular script to work, and hoping you all can help!

The issue seems simple: taking the selected value from a dropdown box and writing it to a text input field. In fact, I've successfully performed the action I'm trying to do in my own separate HTML file using the code below (which is also nearly identical to the code I've added to the form, save the couple of points where I added comments to explain the differences). But Dubsado must have some kind of code taking precedence and preventing me from editing their input fields. Can you think of a way to override/outsmart it?

For reference and testing, I've created a sample version of this form, which you can view at [THIS LINK](https://hello.dubsado.com:443/public/form/view/640274e7a895b2c22a150cf8). Whatever value is selected in the dropdown should also be added to the input field with the placeholder "Photog's name appears here...".

```
<p>Choose a photographer from the following:</p>
<select id="photographerSelect">
  <option>Photographer A</option>
  <option>Photographer B</option>
  <option>Photographer C</option>
</select>
<p id="printName">Photographer name goes here.</p>

<!-- The following only exists in this HTML file. We replace it with an actual Dubsado form field when creating the Dubsado form. -->
<input class="form-element__input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Photog's name appears here after selection above." value="" style="color: rgb(41, 46, 53); font-size: 14px;">

<script>
{
  let selectedPhotographer = document.getElementById("photographerSelect");

  let printArea = document.getElementById("printName");

  let photogText = document.getElementsByClassName("form-element__input")[0];
// NOTE: In the actual Dubsado form, this variable declaration reads document.getElementById("label__6402719d5f8ab90000086e15").getElementsByClassName("form-element__input")[0]; as Dubsado does not assign an ID to any given input field, but does assign one to their parent containers.

  selectedPhotographer.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    console.log(`Selected photographer is: ${event.target.value}`);
    printArea.textContent = `Selected photographer is: ${event.target.value}`;
    photogText.value = event.target.value;
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is your console.log statement in the change event getting triggered?

Comment: @rphello101 It is, but I'm also getting this TypeError each time the change event is triggered: TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'value')
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:12:22) (seems pretty clear to me that's part of the issue here.

Comment: That sounds like your photogText variable may not be set. It may not be finding the element defined. Try outputting that element to the console: "console.log(photgText)". It will probably say "undefined", which means your document.getElementsByClassName("form-element__input")[0] is not finding an element